# PHP MySQL foreign key sorting

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables, one is "Posts" and other is "Comments" that have foreign key from Posts.
How to display Posts by most Comments

Post Table

```
+----+-------+--------------+
| Id | Name  | Message      |
+====+=======+==============+
| 1  | John  | John's msg   |
| 2  | Marco | Marco's msg  |
| 3  | Ivan  | Ivan's msg   |
+----+-------+--------------+
```

Comment table, PostId is foreign key

```
+----+-------+--------------+--------+
| Id | Name  | Comment      | PostId |
+====+=======+==============+========+
| 1  | John  | John's msg   | 2      |
| 2  |Joseph |Joseph's msg  | 2      |
| 3  | Ivan  | Ivan's msg   | 2      |
| 4  |Natalie|Natalie's msg | 1      |
+----+-------+--------------+--------+
```

On frontend page Posts would be sorted by id 2 as it have most comments, then 1, and post id 2 as last.

**Solution thx to GurV:**

```
select p.*,
    (
        select count(*) cnt
        from comments c
        where c.postid = p.id
        ) cnt
from posts p
order by cnt desc;
```

Comment: Come on. Try something.

Comment: Have you actually tried anything or just come here for a quick answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find count of comments for each post in a subquery and join it with posts table to perform sorting on the found count:

```
select p.*
from posts p
left join (
    select postid, count(*) cnt from
    comments 
    group by postid
) c on p.id = c.postid
order by c.cnt desc;
```

If you are going to fetch all the posts there are, then the above will be as fastest it can get.

If it's going to be for a few posts, you can use a correlated query to find counts and then sort by it.

```
select p.*,
    (
        select count(*) cnt
        from comments c
        where c.postid = p.id
        ) cnt
from posts p
order by cnt desc;
```

Comment: what will happen if tables get very large ? This could slow down performance

Comment: @Energizem - Updated with a more details and an alternate solution

Comment: 1st solution shows only posts with 1 or more comments, posts with 0 comments aren't selected.

2nd solution works as expected, thank you

Comment: @Energizem - That was because of the inner join. Changed it to LEFT JOIN. Updated my answer. You can try now

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to group by Post.Id after joining

```
SELECT Post.Id, Post.Name, Post.Message, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Comment.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) as Comments
FROM Post 
LEFT JOIN Comment ON Post.Id = PostId
GROUP BY Post.Id, Post.Name, Post.Message
ORDER BY Comments DESC
```

Comment: @Energizem I'll modify to use a `LEFT JOIN` which should do the trick.